# Using Pi as an intermediary between 2 LANs

Tags: wifi, ethernet, home-automation, access-point, mqtt

I have one raspberry pi which is running Hassio (Home automation stuff). Normally I would just connect the devices I wanted to automate to home LAN but the problem is my wifi SSID & Password might need to be changed and then having to manually update each and every device will be a pain.

So here is what I thought:

1. Connect the pi running hassio to LAN.
2. Connect another pi to LAN using Ethernet.
3. Use the onboard wifi chip on pi to create an Access point.
4. Connect all nodes (devices I want to automate) to this access point.
5. ???
6. Somehow manage to send data from pi (hassio) to pi (Intermediary) to
   Nodes.

Here is an image better describing the connection I have in mind:
[image]

I want to know if something like this is even possible? if yes how should I go about setting it up?

I'm fairly new to Pi and networking so any help would be very much appreciated.

**Updates** from comments:
What I need is a "Smart" Access point, supposing I use a spare one to create an access point, How would I use it? What I need is an "Access Point" that is separate from my home LAN wifi but I still want to be able to send MQTT msgs from the pi running on my home LAN to it.

Pi will be connected using wired Ethernet, the "Devices" (NodeMCUs) that I want to automate will be connected using wifi, my home wifi's ssid is not under my control (It's a bit complicated to explain) and it can change. Therefore I want to create a secondary LAN formed by using the Pi and connect all the NodeMCUs to that LAN using wifi. This secondary LAN needs to be able to communicate with my existing Home LAN because that is where my Pi with Hassio running on it is connected.

Comment: The thing you're trying to create is just an access point. You can buy them for about £20 or equivalent in your local currency, all configured and ready to go. TPLink make some good ones, for example. If you just want to solve the problem, that's what I'd do. If you want to learn how to do it using a Pi, at double the price, then fair enough. (Google "raspberry pi access point" and perhaps you'll find what you need.)

Comment: I do not understand the problem. With a wired LAN you do not need a ssid and a password to connect. And why isn't it required to change ssid and password on the intermediary access point?

Comment: @MarkSmith What I need is a "Smart" Access point, supposing I use a spare one to create an access point, How would I use it?

What I need is an "Access Point" that is separate from my home LAN wifi but I still want to be able to send MQTT msgs from the pi running on my home LAN to it.

Does it make sense? I can elaborate more if that helps.

Comment: @Ingo Pi will be connected using wired Ethernet, the "Devices" (NodeMCUs) that I want to automate will be connected using wifi, my home wifi's ssid is not under my control (It's a bit complicated to explain) and it can change.

Therefore I want to create a secondary LAN formed by using the Pi and connect all the NodeMCUs to that LAN using wifi. This secondary LAN needs to be able to communicate with my existing Home LAN because that is where my Pi with Hassio running on it is connected.

Does it make sense?

Comment: What is "smart" about that, please? In what sense will it be a "separate LAN"? It sounds just like a normal access point to me.

Comment: As far as I understand the Pi(Hassio) and Pi(intermediary) can be connected wired with an ethernet cable, isn't? That would be the line labled "MQTT".

Comment: Can you confirm my previous comment?